# How do I configure Jenkins to point to my VM Project and XML?

Tags: xml, svn, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in my virtual machine (CentOS) and managed to start the Jenkins through browser at port 8888 (custom). Also in my VM I have installed PHP Code Sniffer to get the check style and save the errors and warnings in a XML file. Now I want to create a job in Jenkins to display the result of phpcs XML on my dashboard.

The problem is, that when I create a job, the job is configured to checkout from a SVN repository, what I don't want because I switch between branches in my VM. I want the XML file to be used from the particular branch on my VM not SVN server.

Can someone help me to configure Jenkins to point to my VM Project and XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, from review, improved title (problem statement) , fixed spelling and removed unnecessary closing,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom workspace in your job configuration, so the job will 'work' in that directory.
Therefore you have to check **Advanced Project Options -> Use custom workspace** and type in the path, where you have checked out your repository.
You should also set *Source-Code-Management* to *None*, since you want to manage your branches manually in your VM.

Comment: Thank you SevenEleven, I Tried this but how to put the address of VM on Custom Workspace , e.g.. if my VM IP is 192.168.2.1 and my home folder is /home/ashish.kumar   in VM using my username and password. i use to connect to VM using smb://ashish.kumar@192.168.2.1/ashish.kumar in My MAC Machine

Comment: Since your Jenkins instance runs in your VM (same as where you have checked out your SVN repository) you only have to specify the path to your repository. E.g.: /home/<username>/myRepository

Comment: Thanks SevenEleven, It Worked.